# Joomla 3.0: Can i change the order in which the contact information is displayed

Tags: layout, joomla, contacts

**By default it is:**

> Street and street number
>
> City
>
> Region
>
> Postal code
>
> Country
>
> etc

**But I would like to be able to change this order to**:

> Street and street number
>
> Postal code
>
> City
>
> Region
>
> Country
>
> etc

I would like to do this without having to install extra extensions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change it by using template overrides. See http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core for how overrides work.

The file in question is `/components/com_contact/views/contact/tmpl/default_address.php` which means you have to create a file `/templates/yourtemplate/html/com_contact/contact/default_address.php` where you make the needed changes.

Answer (score 4):

There is actually no way by doing this without overriding the template.
But it's pretty easy to overrides things in Joomla. Just copy the files from

components/com_contact/views/contact

to

templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/html/com_contact/contact

So you can edit the markup and change the ordering like you want.

You can find more informations about overriding on JDocs: [Joomla Documentation: Overrides](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core)